# Many to many persistence ruby mongoid

Tags: ruby, persistence, many-to-many, mongoid

Hey this is my first post so tell me if I am not giving you enough information

So, I am trying out ruby1.9.2 and using mongoid2.2.0 with mongodb1.8.2 and I am having trouble persisting database documents in the code with a many to many relationship.

```
require 'mongoid'
require 'mongo'

Mongoid.load!("../Configurations/mongoid.yml")

Mongoid.configure do |config|
  config.master = Mongo::Connection.new.db("godfather")
end

connection = Mongo::Connection.new
connection.drop_database("godfather")
database = connection.db("godfather")

class Project
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  key :name
  field :numPeople, type: Integer
  has_and_belongs_to_many :people
end

class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  key :name
  field :numProjects, type: Integer, default: 0
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects

  def add_project(project_name)
    project = Project.create(name: project_name)
    self.numProjects = self.numProjects + 1
    self.projects << project
    self.save
  end
  def has_project?(project_name)
    self.projects.each do |project|
      if project.name.upcase == project_name.upcase
        return true
      end
    end
    return false
  end
end

database = Project.create(name: "Database")

alice = Person.create(name: "Alice")
alice.add_project("Database")
puts "has project? #{alice.has_project?("Database")}"#outputs true


puts "Alice has #{alice.numProjects} projects"#outputs 1 
puts "Alice really has #{alice.projects.size} projects"#outputs 1 

editor = Project.create(name: "Editor")

john = Person.create(name: "John")
john.has_project?("Editor")
john.add_project("Editor")
puts "has project? #{john.has_project?("Editor")}"#outputs false

puts "John has #{john.numProjects} projects"#outputs 1 
puts "John really has #{john.projects.size} projects"#outputs 0

operatingSystem = Project.create(name: "OperatingSystem")
drinking = Project.create(name: "Drinking")

henry = Person.create(name: "Henry")
henry.add_project("OperatingSystem")
henry.has_project?("OperatingSystem")
henry.add_project("drinking")
henry.add_project("Editor")

puts "Henry has #{henry.numProjects} projects"#outputs 3
puts "Henry really has #{henry.projects.size} projects"# outputs 3
```

So the problem is John outputs that he has 0 projects when I have added one.

The weird thing is when I use the mongo terminal to inspect the database it shows john having the one project "Editor" which the code did not find in john.projects.size.

Ideally the order in which i call add_project and has_project? should not affect the code and matter.

- thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't see anything wrong with your code but I got the same results as you running it here.

Looks like it could be a known issue - https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/1198

Comment: Oh ok its being worked on.  I guess I can wait for a fix.  reload works for now.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to set autosave to true

see: http://mongoid.org/docs/upgrading.html (search on the page for autosave)